# Run activity on background

Tags: android, android-service

I'm developing an app for testing purposes for my company. This app receives notifications via GPRS of a remote hardware, that indicates things like if it is On/Off, battery level/ etc...

To make this easy to interpret, I'm using images that represent these states, and these are shown in a fragment. The app has nice visual design, including new desing library features as navigation drawer, etc.

To read received messages from the socket I use a service.

The problem is that, if I have the app opened, everything shows fine, but if I have the app closed, and even the service notifies that something has been received, when reopening the app it's starts in it's default state. So, everytime I close the app (exit from it), it is getting destroyed.

I'm not sure on how could I manage this. The best would be if I could mantain the app running on background, but I think that this can't be done.

So, how could I save the state of the activity, to when I open it again, to have everything like before closing it?

Comment: If you deliver state using events (eg EventBus) you can use sticky events. Otherwise, you should probably save the state somewhere (SharedPreferences, Database) and when activity opens load the state from there.

Comment: the "state" is kept in your `Service`, just call `bindService` and ask its current "state"

Comment: have you ever tried "local bound service" pattern?

Comment: @pskink not sure about you are talking, so I guess I haven't.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) ?

Comment: Yes, that's why I say that when I exit from it, it is getting destroyed. I could use sharedPreferences to save each state, but I would like to know if there is another way of achieving this.

Comment: I am not really sure but I think you could use static global variable to save the state.